# Are surnames only written with kanji?

Tags: kanji, katakana, names, hiragana

I wondered about this. I know the first name can be written in Hiragana, Katakata, Kanji (and maybe a mix of it?) but how is it with family names? I think I've never seen one which was mixed, Hiragana or Katakana unless it was a stage or foreign name. Do surnames not only with Kanji exist?

Answer (score 6):

Quite a few ***family names*** contain kana in them.  There is no law restricting the use of kana in family names, either.

I have personally met people with family names like:

[一ノ瀬]{いちのせ}、[二ノ宮]{にのみや}、[一ツ松]{ひとつまつ}、[藤ヶ崎]{ふじがさき}, [城ケ崎]{じょうがさき}, etc.

A quick search on the internet will give you these as well:

https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1441711159?__ysp=44Kr44OK44KS5L2%2F44Gj44Gf6IuX5a2X

https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q13144926323?__ysp=44Gy44KJ44GM44GqIOOCq%2BOCv%2BOCq%2BODiiDlhaXjgaPjgZ%2Flp5M%3D